# breadth first search error

Tags: java, runtime-error, directed-graph, breadth-first-search

[image: digraph]
[image: matrix]

```
public int bfs(int maxDepth){ //maxDepth = 3 works.. maxDepth = 4 gives me an error
        int src = 0;
        int dest = 2;
        int nodes = arr[src].length - 1;
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[nodes + 1];
        int i;
        int countDepth = 0;
        int countPaths = 0;
        int element;


        queue.add(src);

        while(!queue.isEmpty() || countDepth != maxDepth)
        {
            element = queue.remove();
            i = element;

            while(i <= nodes)
            {
                if(arr[element][i] > 0 && visited[i] == false)
                {
                    queue.add(i);
                    visited[i] = true;

                    if(arr[i][element] > 0) //if it has two directions
                        visited[i] = false;

                    if(element ==  dest || i == dest)
                        countPaths++;
                }

                i++;
            }

            countDepth++;
        }

        return countPaths;
    }
```

I'm trying to go 'x' amount of levels deep while counting the # of paths to the destination.

For some reason I keep getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(Unknown Source)
at java.util.LinkedList.remove(Unknown Source)
at Graph.bfs(Graph.java:48)
```

I don't understand what's going on. It seems to work when I go 3 levels deep but when I change it to 4, it doesn't work.

Comment: which line in this function is line 48?

Comment: element = queue.remove()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`while(!queue.isEmpty() || countDepth != maxDepth)`

to

`while(!queue.isEmpty() && countDepth != maxDepth)`

Each graph has some maximal depth. It seems, you set maxDepth larger than it's really possible for given graph and your loop tries to continue *bfsing* even after handling all possible nodes (i.e when queue is empty)

**UPDATE**
I will try to provide answer to your second question you posted in comments even if given information actually is not enough, so, I will try to be extrasens=)
I guess, you are going to calculate all paths of `length=1`, of `length=2..` `length=givenMaxDepth|maxPossibleDepth`. I saw `queue` data structure but I didn't see declaration - **are you using the same queue for all function calls? If yes, you should clear queue after each call** (best place to call `queue.clear()` is before return statement).

Also, I see you are using new visited array in each call and it's correct but if you actually using some global visited you also should "clear" visited after each call - in other words fill it with false.

Comment: Thanks a lot... That solved the error. Now its outputting the wrong number of correct paths. It should print out '4' but it's printing out '1'.

It prints out the correct path when I do 3 levels but I'm assuming that it is a coincidence and my algorithm is incorrect.

Comment: @juice, I think I solved 'NoSuchElementException' error but I can't give an answer to your second question because you didn't provide task description=) If you want to get answer to incorrect output, provide **full information** - code, input, expected output, incorrect output, problem statement e.t.c

Comment: @juice:  You should ask your new question as, well, a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), not a rider on an old one.  (There's a fair chance that, in composing your new question, you will figure the problem out on your own.  That happens a lot.)

Comment: @juice, see update. Is my suggestion correct? If yes I may call myself an extrasens=)